# http4s - get request body as String or InputStream

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream, http4s

I'm trying to define `HttpService` that receives json and parses it to case class with `json4s` library:

```
import org.http4s._
import org.http4s.dsl._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

case class Request(firstName: String, secondName: String)

HttpService {
  case req @ POST -> Root =>
    val request = parse(<map req.body or req.bodyAsText to JsonInput>).extract[Request]
    Ok()
}
```

How can I get `org.json4s.JsonInput` from `req.body` or `req.bodyAsText`?

I know that `json4s` also have `StringInput` and `StreamInput` that inherits from `JsonInput` for using with `String` and `InputStream` so I think that I need to convert `req.body` to `InputStream` or `req.bodyAsText` to `String` but I still do not understand how.

I'm new to Scala and I do not yet fully understand some concepts such as `scalaz.stream.Process`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `http4s-json4s-jackson` (or `http4s-json4s-native`) packages and use an `org.http4s.EntityDecoder` to easily get a `Foo` (I renamed your `Request` case class to `Foo` below) from a request.

`EntityDecoder` is a type class which can decode an entity from the request body.
We want to get the `Foo` posted in JSON, so we need to create an `EntityDecoder[Foo]` which can decode JSON. If we want to create this decoder using json4s we need a `Reader` (or a `JsonFormat`).

If you have an `EntityDecoder[Foo]` instance, we can get the `Foo` from the request with `req.as[Foo]`.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

import org.http4s._
import org.http4s.dsl._
import org.http4s.json4s.jackson._

case class Foo(firstName: String, secondName: String)

// create a json4s Reader[Foo]
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
implicit val fooReader = new Reader[Foo] { 
  def read(value: JValue): Foo = value.extract[Foo] 
}
// create a http4s EntityDecoder[Foo] (which uses the Reader)
implicit val fooDec = jsonOf[Foo]

val service = HttpService {
  case req @ POST -> Root => 
    // req.as[Foo] gives us a Task[Foo]
    // and since Ok(...) gives a Task[Response] we need to use flatMap
    req.as[Foo] flatMap ( foo => Ok(foo.firstName + " " + foo.secondName) )
}
```

---

*Note: The json libraries libraries used most often with http4s are probably [argonaut](http://argonaut.io/) and [circe](http://circe.io/). So you might find more http4s examples using one of those libraries.*

Answer (score 6):

Peter's solution both corrects the question and answers it, but I stumbled here looking for the solution to OP's stated, but not intended, question: "how to get request body as [...] InputStream" in `http4s`. Thanks to the discussion in [Issue 634](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/issues/634) on GitHub, here's what I came up with:

```
import java.io.InputStream
import org.http4s._
implicit val inputStreamDecoder: EntityDecoder[InputStream] = 
    EntityDecoder.decodeBy(MediaRange.`*/*`) { msg =>
  DecodeResult.success(scalaz.stream.io.toInputStream(msg.body))
}
```

And then in your HttpService, use that decoder like so:

```
request.as[InputStream].flatMap { inputStream => ...inputStream is an InputStream... }
```

Or skip the whole Decoder dance, if you want:

```
val inputStream = scalaz.stream.io.toInputStream(request.body)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `flatMap` and `as` *inside* it before calling the Http4s service to decode responses from it:

```
@Test def `Get json gives valid contact`: Unit = {
    val request = Request[IO](GET, uri"/contact")
    val io = Main.getJsonWithContact.orNotFound.run(request)
    // here is magic
    val response = io.flatMap(_.as[Json]).unsafeRunSync()

    val contact = contactEncoder(Contact(1, "Denis", "123"))  // this is encoding to json for assertion
    assertEquals(contact, response)
}
```

This is how types work here:

```
val io: IO[Response[IO]] = Main.getJsonWithContact.orNotFound.run(request)
val response: IO[Json] = io.flatMap(_.as[Json])
val res: Json = response.unsafeRunSync()
```

`as[String]` will return the string just like this.